# Blending sprite with pre-existing texture

Tags: opengl

I am just learning the intricacies of OpenGL. What I would like to do is render a sprite onto a pre-existing texture. The texture will consist of terrain with some points alpha=1 and some points alpha=0. I would like the sprite to appear on a pixel of the texture if and only if the corresponding texture's pixel's alpha = 0. That is, for each pixel of the sprite, the output colour is:

Color of the sprite, if terrain alpha = 0.

Color of the terrain, if terrain alpha = 1.

Is this possible to do with blending function, if not how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact opposite of the traditional blending function. The usual blend function is a linear interpolation between the source and destination colors, based on the source alpha.

What you want is a linear interpolation between the source and destination colors, based on the *destination* alpha. But you also want to invert the usual meaning; a destination alpha of 1 means that the destination color should be taken, not the source color.

That's pretty easy.

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_DST_ALPHA);
```

However, the above assumes that your sprites do not themselves have some from of inherent transparency. And most sprites do. That is, if the sprite alpha is 0 at some pixel, you don't want to overwrite the terrain color, no matter what the terrain's alpha is.

That makes this whole process excessively difficult. Pre-multiplying the alpha will not save you either, since black will just as easily overwrite the color in the terrain if there is no terrain color there.

In effect, you would need to do a linear interpolation based on neither the source nor the destination, but on a combination of them. I think multiplication of the two (src-alpha * (1 - dst-alpha)) would do a good job.

This is not possible with OpenGL's [standard blending system](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending). You would need to employ some form of programmatic blending technique. This typically involves read/modify/write operations using [NV/ARB_texture_barrier](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Barrier) or otherwise [ping-ponging](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Framebuffer_objects) between bound textures.

Comment: Thanks very much, exactly what I was looking for. By a pleasant coincidence, the sprite I am drawing really has no transparencies (it's a bridge tile).

Steve